# se puede crear objetos en java Poo en diferentes clases?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Tengo un código que me pasaron en donde tiene 3 clases diferentes:

1 clase que se llama **principal** donde tiene el **main** y tiene un objeto creado:

```
OpcionesConversion conversion = new OpcionesConversion();
```

1 clase que se llama **OpcionesConversion** donde tiene otro objeto creado y métodos:

```
ConvertirMonedas monedas = new ConvertirMonedas();
```

1 clase que se llama **ConvertirMonedas** con solo métodos.

Se puede hacer eso?, construir objetos diferentes en cualquier clase?, he buscado y no he encontrado respuesta ya que apenas estoy estudiando, pero ya pase por **poo**,  y todo lo que veo, es que en la clase principal que contiene el **main** es donde construyes el objeto usando los atributos y constructores y métodos que tiene otra clase, ya tu sabes si usas clases abstractas, herencia, interfaces, enums pero nunca he visto que en estas clases construyas objetos, se que se puede pero nunca he visto que lo hagan, lo que siempre veo es que estructuran las cosas de la siguiente manera, creas tu clase con tus atributos, métodos, constructores etc, y creas otra clase que es principal **main** donde ya empiezas a construir objetos.
Dejo el código que les comento para que me digan si se puede hacer, revisen los objetos que se construyen.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpcionesConversion conversion = new OpcionesConversion();

    while(true) {
        String opciones = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Seleccione una opción de conversión", "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                new Object[] {"Conversor de Monedas", "Conversor de Temperatura"}, "Elegir").toString();

        switch(opciones) {
            case "Conversor de Monedas":
                String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese el valor a convertir");
                double valorRecibido = Double.parseDouble(input);
                conversion.ConvertirMonedas(valorRecibido);
                int respuesta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "¿Desea realizar otra Conversión?");
                if(JOptionPane.OK_OPTION == respuesta) {
                    System.out.println("Entra");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Programa finalizado");
                }
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Clase con otro objeto y métodos, no se por que no me deja meter el objeto dentro del código que pegue.

```
"ConvertirMonedas monedas = new ConvertirMonedas();

public void ConvertirMonedas(double valor) {
    String opcion = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Elije la moneda que deseas convertir tu dinero ",  "Monedas",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]
                    {"De Pesos a Dólar", "De Pesos a Euro", "De Pesos a Libras Esterlinas", "De Pesos a Yen Japonés", "De Pesos a Won sub-coreano", "De Dólar a Pesos", "De Euro a Pesos", "De Libras Esterlinas a Pesos", "De Yen Japonés a Pesos", "De Won sub-coreano a Pesos"},
            "Seleccion")).toString();

    switch (opcion) {
        case "De Pesos a Dólar":
            monedas.ConvertirPesosArgentinoDolares(valor);
            break;

        case "De Pesos a Euro":
            monedas.ConvertirPesosArgentinoEuros(valor);
            break;

        case "De Pesos a Libras Esterlinas":
            monedas.ConvertirPesosArgentinoLibra(valor);
            break;

        case "De Pesos a Yen Japonés":
            monedas.ConvertirPesosArgentinoYen(valor);
            break;

        case "De Pesos a Won sub-coreano":
            monedas.ConvertirPesosArgentinoWon(valor);
            break;

        case "De Dólar a Pesos":
            monedas.ConvertirDolaresPesosArgentino(valor);
            break;

        case "De Euro a Pesos":
            monedas.ConvertirEurosPesosArgentino(valor);
            break;

        case "De Libras Esterlinas a Pesos":
            monedas.ConvertirLibraPesosArgentino(valor);
            break;

        case "De Yen Japonés a Pesos":
            monedas.ConvertirYenPesosArgentino(valor);
            break;

        case "De Won sub-coreano a Pesos":
            monedas.ConvertirWonPesosArgentino(valor);
            break;
    }
}"
```

Clase con solo métodos

```
public class ConvertirMonedas {

    public void ConvertirPesosArgentinoDolares(double valor) {
        double monedaDolar = valor / 137.68;
        monedaDolar = (double)Math.round(monedaDolar * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes $ " + monedaDolar + " Dolares");
    }

    public void ConvertirPesosArgentinoEuros(double valor) {
        double monedaEuro = valor / 137.20;
        monedaEuro = (double)Math.round(monedaEuro * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes $ " + monedaEuro + " Euros");
    }

    public void ConvertirPesosArgentinoLibra(double valor) {
        double monedaLibra = valor / 161.52;
        monedaLibra = (double)Math.round(monedaLibra * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes $ " + monedaLibra + " Libras Esterlinas");
    }

    public void ConvertirPesosArgentinoYen(double valor) {
        double monedaYen = valor / 1;
        monedaYen = (double)Math.round(monedaYen * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes $ " + monedaYen + " Yen Japonés");
    }

    public void ConvertirPesosArgentinoWon(double valor) {
        double monedaWon = valor / 0.1;
        monedaWon = (double)Math.round(monedaWon * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes $ " + monedaWon + " Won sub-coreano");
    }

    public void ConvertirDolaresPesosArgentino(double valor) {
        double monedaDolar = 137.68 * valor;
        monedaDolar = (double)Math.round(monedaDolar * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes Dolares " + monedaDolar + " en pesos");
    }

    public void ConvertirEurosPesosArgentino(double valor) {
        double monedaEuro = valor * 137.20;
        monedaEuro = (double)Math.round(monedaEuro * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes Euros " + monedaEuro + " en pesos");
    }

    public void ConvertirLibraPesosArgentino(double valor) {
        double monedaLibra = valor * 161.52;
        monedaLibra = (double)Math.round(monedaLibra * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes Libras Esterlinas " + monedaLibra + " en pesos");
    }

    public void ConvertirYenPesosArgentino(double valor) {
        double monedaYen = valor * 1;
        monedaYen = (double)Math.round(monedaYen * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes Yen Japonés " + monedaYen + " en pesos");
    }

    public void ConvertirWonPesosArgentino(double valor) {
        double monedaWon = valor * 0.1;
        monedaWon = (double)Math.round(monedaWon * 100d) /100 ;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tienes Won sub-coreano " + monedaWon + " en pesos");
    }
}
```

ayudenme a entender

Comment: Sí, un objeto puede crear objetos de otras clases según lo necesite. La clase principal se usa como un punto de inicio para la ejecución del programa pero no significa que solo ahí pueden crearse objetos.

Comment: POO es programacion orientada a objetoS (notese la S)... podes tener tantos objetos como quieras, donde quieras y como gustes.. usualmente el main (o el punto de entrada en otro lenguaje) es solo eso, el punto de entrada, pero tu programa podria vivir dentro de otro metodo, en otra clase... o sea si... se puede y es mas, te diria que es lo recomendable...

Answer (score 0):

Se puede crear objetos de cualquier clase desde cualquier objeto, siempre y cuando el objeto en cuestión tenga acceso a la clase de la que se quiere crear un nuevo objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes, no, no es necesario crear objetos en el **main**, como te indican en los comentarios, el **main** es la puerta de entrada a la aplicación, te muestro lo que suele ser "mi" típico **main**:

```
public class ProgramaX {
    Gui gui;

    void iniciar() {
        gui = new Gui();
        hagoCosas();
    }  

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ProgramaX  pro = newProgramaX();
        pro.iniciar();
    }
}
```

La única razón por la que creo el objeto **ProgramaX**, es filosófica, no crear métodos estáticos, a menos que necesite métodos estáticos, podría tranquilamente usar dentro del **main** la llamada **iniciar()** (habiendo declarado el método iniciar como estático).

Veamos tu idea de **main**... (resumido)

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    OpcionesConversion conversion = new OpcionesConversion();
    ConvertirMonedas monedas = new ConvertirMonedas();
    ConvertirTemperaturas temperaturas = new ConvertirTemperaturas();

    while( true ) {
        String opciones = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Seleccione una opción de conversión", "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                new Object[] { "Conversor de Monedas", "Conversor de Temperatura" }, "Elegir" ).toString();

        switch( opciones ) {
            case "Conversor de Monedas":
            case "Conversor de Temperaturas":
```

Si el usuario elije convertir solo temperaturas, creaste el objeto **monedas** que nunca vas a usar, con el consiguiente gasto de recursos.
Para evitar eso, instanciamos los objetos cuando los necesitamos.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    OpcionesConversion conversion = new OpcionesConversion();

    while( true ) {
        String opciones = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( null, "Seleccione una opción de conversión", "Menú", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
                new Object[] { "Conversor de Monedas", "Conversor de Temperatura" }, "Elegir" ).toString();

        switch( opciones ) {
            case "Conversor de Monedas":
                ConvertirMonedas monedas = new ConvertirMonedas();

            case "Conversor de Temperaturas":
                ConvertirTemperaturas temperaturas = new ConvertirTemperaturas();
```

Con respecto a porqué no puedes poner el objeto dentro de tu código, en principio, la única retricción es no crear un objeto denro de su propia clase:

```
class Tomate {
    Tomate tomi = new Tomate();  // genera un bucle infinito 
    Tomate tom;
    Tomate() {
        tom = new Tomate();   // genera un bucle infinito 
    }
}
```

Esto crearía un bucle infinito, ya que creas el objeto que intenta crear otro, que intenta crear otro...
Lo que veo, es que has puesto tu código entre comillas, no se si fue un error al copiarlo aquí, o lo tienes así en tu aplicación, en cuyo caso, debes suprimirlo.
En resumen, durante el aprendisaje, se utiliza el instanciar objetos en el **main**, en la práctica, no suele ser el camino más adecuado, aunque siempre puede haber escenarios donde sea perfectamente válido.
Espero que mi torpe explicación te haya aclarado un poco el tema, si tienes más dudas, no dudes (terrible contradicción) en pedir explicaciones extra.

Comment: hola que tal muchísimas gracias por tu explicación, con respecto a lo de las comillas, al querer copiar todo el código de la clase no me dejaba pegarlo completo y bueno fue un problema técnico con la pagina jeje, y al respecto de tu comentario aprendí mucho, son cosas que no ves en clases ya que siempre siguen el patrón de todo en main

Comment: Me alegra mucho haberte ayudado.